# Advanages/Disadvantages of using pointer

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I am learning C++ and I have been reading and learning about trees lately. I was wondering, what is the advantage of using pointers?

For example if I have a class Node, and I have a function called Function,
what is the difference between having

```
  Function (Node *node) 
  Function (Node node)
```

I know one takes a pointer as a paremeter and the other does not. But I don't understand completely what is the difference.

Comment: It depends on how `Node` is defined, and what the function is supposed to do.

Comment: Roughly equivalent to "In life, what are the advantages of air vs. water?"

Answer (score 2):

```
Function(Node node)
```

makes a copy of the argument. In particular, the function can never modify the original argument, so if you manipulate node in Function, the code where you called Function(node) won't see those changes.

Sometimes you want that, so that other people can't mess up your data.

For large objects, the time required to copy the data is also a downside of not using the pointer.

Comment: You should upvote or accept the answer if it helped you. That's the way this site works.

Comment: you should not only upvote but also accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

With `Function (Node *node)` you *can* modify contents of `node` in function definition.

With `Function (Node node)` you *cannot* modify contents of `node` in function definition.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is variable that stores the *location* of another variable.

So a     Node * nodePointer will have a value something like this: x000000FF which is an address in virtual memory.  If you pass this address, the function can modify whatever resides at that address, in this case your node object.  If you pass the object itself, it will be a copy of the object, so the original object will be unchanged when the method returns.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking in:

```
Function (Node *node) 
Function (Node node)
```

- the first allows a "null" value to be passed (= `0` or `nullptr`)
- the first can modify the objecy
- the second requires that `Node` have a copy constructor
- the second is less efficient if `sizeof(Node)` > `sizeof(Node*)`

Answer (score 0):

First you must understand what an object is.

```
House home;
```

This creates storage for an instance of class 'House' on the stack, calls the constructor and designates the name "home" to refer to it subsequently.

The object now occupies space on the stack, but the stack is just an area of memory that has been designated for use as the stack. The same way that "Central Drive" was so named because when it was built it ran down the center of town, today it's just a way of distinguishing one road from another.

When we talk about pass by value, e.g.

```
int SendGift(House h, Gift g)
```

this means that when we call this function we make a new, local copy of the House we call with for the function to manipulate.

```
void SendGift(House h, Gift g)
{
    h.porch.insert(g);
    g.setLocation(h);
}
```

Both "House h" and "Gift g" are **temporary** local variables of the function SendGift, so if we call it this way:

```
House home;
Gift gift(Gift::Dollars, 1 * 1000 * 1000);
SendGift(home, gift);
```

the variable "home" is untouched, as is the gift; all the changes we made were to "g" and "h" and they went away when the function ended.

The code was intended to say "Make a gift of a million dollars and deliver that to the hosue at 123 Beech Street". But because we passed by value, what it actually said was "Make a gift of a million dollars. Make a copy of the house and the gift, and place the copy into the copy-house, then destroy both of them."

It can also be very expensive, if the "House" object is several Kb big, then every time you pass by value, a lot of data has to be copied into the temporary.

With small objects, like integers, this is No Big Deal(TM). But with large objects, like a house, this is way too costly.

So instead we might want to pass by pointer:

```
int SendGift(House* h, Gift* g)
{
    h->porch.insert(g);
    g->setLocation(h);
}
```

A pointer is variable containing an address, the location in memory of an instance of an object. So instead of copying the house, brick by brick, into a temporary in SendGift, we passed the address. So now our call

So, then, there are two primary reasons to pass by pointer (or reference):

1. When you want to allow a function to modify the contents of the object it is being called with,
2. When you want to minimize the cost of calling the function by avoiding creating copies of the input parameters.

Generally when the intent is #2 and not #1 you should mark the parameter as const.

```
#include <iostream>

struct BigObj
{
    BigObj() : m_useCount(0) {}

    int m_useCount;
    int m_stuff[4096];
};

void BigObjByValue(BigObj b)
{
    b.m_useCount++;
    std::cout << "BigObjByValue " << (&b) << ". m_useCount is now " << b.m_useCount << std::endl;
}

void BigObjByPtr(BigObj* b)
{
    b->m_useCount++;
    std::cout << "BigObjByValue " << (b) << ". m_useCount is now " << b->m_useCount << std::endl;
}

void BigObjByConstPtr(const BigObj* b)
{
    //b->m_useCount++; // compiler won't allow this, try uncommenting.
    std::cout << "BigObjByValue " << (b) << ". m_useCount is now " << b->m_useCount << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    BigObj mainB;
    std::cout << "Created mainB at " << (&mainB) << " useCount = " << mainB.m_useCount << std::endl;

    BigObjByValue(mainB);
    std::cout << "in main, m_useCount = " << mainB.m_useCount << std::endl;

    BigObjByPtr(&mainB);
    std::cout << "in main, m_useCount = " << mainB.m_useCount << std::endl;

    BigObjByConstPtr(&mainB);
    std::cout << "in main, m_useCount = " << mainB.m_useCount << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

ideone live demo: http://ideone.com/SjkoNq